# Data too long for column for longtext datatype - MySqlException

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I am trying to insert string in `LONGTEXT` column. Length of string is 75402 and byte count is 150804 (about 147 KB)

[image: Table Structure]

Throws an exception `Data too long for column` On inserting record.

MySQL document state that LONGTEXT can contains maximum 4GB of data

Any suggestion will be welcome

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

> LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 − 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
>   multibyte characters. **The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns
>   also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the
>   client/server protocol and available memory**. Each LONGTEXT value is
>   stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes
>   in the value.

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html